# RxSwift - Fatal error: Abstract method error

Tags: observable, rx-swift

Can so help to resolve this error
[image]

ViewController.swift
this is my code in the viewDidLoad.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    let dataManager = DataManager()
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let viewModel = ViewModel()
        viewModel.fetch(dataManager)
        _ = viewModel.items.subscribe({ books in
            print(books)


        })
    }
}
```

this is the way I implemented items in the viewModel.
**ViewModel.swift**

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift

class ViewModel: ViewModelProtocol {
    var isError: Bool = false
    var message: String?
    typealias T = Book
    var items:Observable<[Book]> = Observable<[Book]>()
    func fetch(_ dataManager: DataManager) {
        dataManager.get(for: .book) { [weak self] results in
            self?.items = Observable<[Book]>.create({ subscriber -> Disposable in
                switch results {
                case .success(let books):
                    subscriber.onNext(books as! [Book])
                    subscriber.onCompleted()
                case .failure(let error):
                    subscriber.onError(error)
                }
                return Disposables.create()
            })

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you show us the line of crashed code from view did load?

Comment: I did add the code. Thx

Comment: Please add a minimal code sample that will reproduce the error. You haven't added enough code. I expect that something is wrong with the way you defined `items`.

Comment: yes. sorry. just edited. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the little code you have provided, I suspect that this is the root of your problem:

```
var items:Observable<[Book]> = Observable<[Book]>()
```

Don't ever make an Observable a `var`. They should only ever be `let` constants. Chances are you are deinit-ing your observable when it is in the middle of sending an event.

If this is not the correct answer then we will not be able to help you until you post a *complete* and *minimal* code sample demonstrating the problem.